# I don't understand why this result come why path add Environment.CurrentDirectory?

Tags: c#

```
private void CommandMethod(object parameter)
        {
            string path = @"‪C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop";
            Teststring = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            Teststring2 = fi.FullName;
        }
```

I Can't Understand why
Teststring2 = "C:\Users\yu_in\source\repos\TestApplication\TestApplication\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows\‪C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop"
why result add Environment.CurrentDirectory ?

Comment: Your line with Environment.CurrentDirectory isn't doing anything. I have a feeling the code in your question is not the code producing that combined string

Comment: The OP's code is perfectly fine. The code can get reduced to `Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(@"‪C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop").FullName);`. When I run that I get `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad7\_zqwllsig\shadow-2\‪C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop` on the Console. That's not behaving correctly.

Comment: This question should be getting up-votes, IMHO.

Comment: I think 'C:\Users\yu_in\source\repos\TestApplication\TestApplication\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows\‪' this path is Environment.CurrentDirectory path. Is this right?

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree about the votes. I switched to an upvote after I realized the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite literally more to this question than meets the eye :)

Your path has an additional, invisible, unicode character at the beginning of it:
`U+202A` (The actual text in your code is: `@"[U+202A]C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop"`). This is making your path invalid, so the constructor of `DirectoryInfo` is attempting to use your provided path as a local path.

Instead of this: `@"‪C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop"`,
use this : `@"C:\Users\yu_in\Desktop"`. I know both paths look the same, but only the second one is a valid path.

Comment: Good pick up. I was stunned. I use `DirectoryInfo` all the time and haven't hit this. I was beginning to pull my hair out trying to get the OP's code to work.

Comment: [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924)'s an article I found about why this problem occurs. The last line is very relevant: *"imagine if you had pasted the path into the source code to a C program!"*

Comment: Thanks ! What is different first one and second one?

Comment: @InsikYoo The answer explains it. What part do you not understand?

Comment: @NigelBess This Problem is just occerd [U+202A] ? string format difference?